# Software to find duplicate pictures within 4TB of data

Tags: windows, duplicate-files

At work We have this massive storage of media (images and videos)
Size is like 4TB over 1 million files

Because of data lost and recovery effort we now have additional 1TB of recovered files, most are duplicate with different names and timestamps.

I tried multiple software to detect duplicates but they simply crash because of the volume.

I need it to point out the copy and its origin based on content.
And do it relatively fast (3 hours?); I was waiting hours (8+ ) on other software before they crashed.

Is there any software that can handle such task?

Operating system is Windows 10

HDD is RAID 1 8TB NTFS
Computer has 8 core i7 CPU 
With 16GB memory

At this point. I am not sure about the price constraints something I need to check after I get a quote.

Comment: Welcome! How do you define "relatively fast"?  What operating system(s)?  How is the volume formatted?  Any price considerations?  Please update your question with more details.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I added Operating system details and more info, let me know what else is missing.

Comment: Thank you for the updates! I added a Windows tag, to indicate that the software is to be for Windows.  Do you have any price constraints?  Also, given that you have a target time duration, you may want to note the hardware specifications of the system on which the software will run.

Comment: Its a win10 that we use for storage, it has 8 core i7 with 16GB memory , i am not sure about the price constraints something i need to check after i get some kind of a price.

Comment: Thanks for the further updates. :)  Please add the details from your last comment to your question.  I hope someone can recommend software that can help you.

Comment: Both current answers are misleading because the talk is about data recovery so OP needs to find duplicate files, not duplicate photos. He does not need a software to compare the images.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a 4TB set of photos at my disposal for testing, but in case you haven't tried the following programs, give them a shot, as they have worked well for me to find duplicate photos:

- VisiPics (http://www.visipics.info/index.php?title=Main_Page): Free.
- Ashisoft Duplicate Photo Finder (https://www.ashisoft.com/duplicate-photo-finder.htm): Not free (USD 40 - 60) but has a free version that you can try. This is my preferred choice. It shows an indicator as it scans for files so perhaps you will be able to gauge how long the whole set will take to compare as it progresses.

Answer (score 2):

Both free and will compare similar images:

- https://www.duplicate-finder.com/photo.html
- https://github.com/saolaolsson/pixiple